# How do I extract string in order (example: 9, 4, 1, 6, 3...) using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is what I have so far, I am trying to extract the numbers for a sudoku grid but I am having trouble extracting the numbers in order. How can I extract the numbers in order so I can get 9,4,1,6,3,8,7 from the following:

````
[<span class="true">9</span>, <span class="vloz"> </span>]
[<span class="sedy">4</span>]
[<span class="sedy">1</span>]
so on....```

    import requests 
    import bs4
    import numpy as np
    import re

    res = requests.get('https://www.sudokuweb.org/')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content)
    paras = soup.select("tr > td")
    #print(paras)
    for para in paras:
        para = para.select("span")
        print(para)
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this. If you want to change column just change column section
items.

```
import requests
import bs4
import numpy as np
import re

res = requests.get('https://www.sudokuweb.org/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
paras = soup.select("div#sudoku.sudoku.nine")
print(paras)

columns = ['td#right']
columns += ["td#right{}".format(x) for x in range(9, 81, 9)]

for i in columns:
    print(i)
    print(soup.select_one(i).find('span').text)
```